# Employer account summary

Tags: feature-request, jobs

On the page to edit my account summary on the employer portal of the careers site, some information is mandatory (such as company).

This does make perfect sense in the general case, but I have information from a position I've since departed. I feel it's not appropriate to store those details as my own. I'm also concerned that I might go "Oops" and if I post a job here it shows up under the old company's name somewhere down the line.

I can't remove the information because it's a mandatory field.

Comment: We now have a new way of storing company information and we are going to remove the old account summary page, with much prejudice.